# ]Unable to launch Android Studio in Ubuntu 14

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio

I enter this command in terminal first I change the directory to terminal and then when I try to  open the studio.sh It gives bash error

```
sarthak@sarthak:~/development$ /android-sdk/bin/studio.sh
bash: /android-sdk/bin/studio.sh: No such file or directory
sarthak@sarthak:~/development$
```

Please Help

Comment: What folder did you choose to install Android Studio into? Your errors above are because you specified `/android-sdk/...` indicating that Android Studio is installed in your root directory (which I'm guessing is wrong).

Answer (score 5):

Because the script file is in bin directory you need to go there to run it.

Go to the bin directory in terminal by doing:

```
cd ../../bin
```

And then run the script by doing:

```
./studio.sh
```

Comment: How to do that?I am new on Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: by cd command


type 
 cd android-sdk/bin/  from /development directory.
CD stand for change directory.

Comment: Still Not Working! sarthak@sarthak:~/development$ cd ~/android-studio/bin/
bash: cd: /home/sarthak/android-studio/bin/: No such file or directory
sarthak@sarthak:~/development$ /development/android-studio/bin/
bash: /development/android-studio/bin/: No such file or directory
sarthak@sarthak:~/development$

Comment: In a Developement directory , only type cd android-studio/bin insted of ~/android-studio.

Answer (score -2):

You can install it from the repository here

[Android studio paolorotolo repository](https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/)

launch it first time from studio.sh in bin directory like this:

```
cd opt/android-studio/bin/
./studio.sh
```

this will launch android studio.

And from android stuio tools tab -> genereate desktop entry to see it in search and programs.

Comment: Still Not Working!!sarthak@sarthak:~/development$ cd ~/android-studio/bin/
 bash: cd: /home/sarthak/android-studio/bin/: No such file or directory
sarthak@sarthak:~/development$ /development/android-studio/bin/
bash: /development/android-studio/bin/: No such file or directory
sarthak@sarthak:~/development$

Comment: Follow instructions in the repo link and write exactly the two lines in the answer